# How to interpolate between two MVP setups?

Tags: shader, matrix, interpolation

I am currently writing an AR experience.
I have a Camera View Matrix, A Camera Perspective matrix and the Model Matrix of the content I display.

The AR content should can be switched to "2D", so it is attached to the screen.

For this, I have predefined Model, View and Projection Matrices.

I would like to create an interpolation between "Content in Room" and "Content attached to screen"
How would I achieve this?
[image]

My first idea was to calculate both MVPs and sending them both to the shaders and giving each shader an interpolation factor (I would interpolate the vertices)
This would work out I think, but I don't know if this causes deformations during interpolation.

Comment: (Very generally speaking)Interpolating between two matrices using euler angles isn't always intuitive and can lead to  artifacts, it may just be a heck of a lot easier to introduce a rotation matrix and either pass it to the shader as a uniform or premultiply the rotation matrix with the model matrix each frame. It looks like this will rotate around the x axis so the actual rotation shouldn't be to hard to calc. There may be a scale involved to I am just now thinking, but there again...it is more like computing your way to the new matrix rather then interpolation.

Comment: Interpolation between rotations is done through slerp for quaternions and there's a corresponding operation for rotation matrices. You provide two orientations and a parameter $t$ to interpolate between. See: https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/RotationIssues.pdf